# Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection'

Tags: ado.net, sql-server-ce

i am using the Ado.Net Entity Framework with Code Only (Tutorial at: [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/pages/feature-ctp-walkthrough-code-only-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)) and i want to be as much database independent as possible.

In my first approach i just want to go for Sql Express and Sql Compact databases.
With Sql Express everthing works fine but with Sql Compact i get the exception mentioned in my question.

Does anybody knows if it is possible to connect to Sql Compact with the Code Only approach? (with a generated .edmx file for a Sql Compact database everthing works fine, but i want to use code only!)

Here is some code:

My Class which is building the DataContext:

```
public class DataContextBuilder : IDataContextBuilder
{
    private readonly DbProviderFactory _factory;

    public DataContextBuilder(DbProviderFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    #region Implementation of IDataContextBuilder

    public IDataContext CreateDataContext(string connectionString)
    {
        var builder = new ContextBuilder<DataContext>();
        RegisterConfiguration(builder);

        var connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        var ctx = builder.Create(connection);

        return ctx;
    }

    #endregion

    private void RegisterConfiguration(ContextBuilder<DataContext> builder)
    {
        builder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
    }
}
```

The line

> var ctx = builder.Create(connection);

is throwing the exception.

The IDataContext is just a simple Interface for the ObjectContext:

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    int SaveChanges();

    IObjectSet<Person> PersonSet { get; }
}
```

My connection string is configured in the app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CompactConnection" connectionString="|DataDirectory|\Test.sdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And the build action is started with

```
var cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompactConnection"];
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(cn.ProviderName);
var builder = new DataContextBuilder(factory);
var context = builder.CreateDataContext(cn.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have to answer my own question.

This works now with the
[Entity Framework CTP 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-feature-ctp4-released)

and
SQL Server Compact 4.0

Comment: you can download Sql Server Compact 4.0 at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/07/07/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had first tried 4.0, but had made a mistake on my own.  Then I tried 3.5 and got no where.  Then I tried 4.0 again, had already fixed my mistake, and saw your answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: This was my problem too.  The SqlServerCe 4.0 installation didn't put the DLLs in the GAL, so I copied them manually to my project and added them.  Thanks.